# Docker: What does docker image contain? In order to pass the saved images across machines, do I have to pass them with the source codes?

Tags: docker

I have copied the images created on one machine and copied that images on a different machine. (docker images are saved using docker save -o [images.tar] command)

Then I use the docker loader command on the other machine. 
In order to run these images, do I have to pass the source codes, the Dockerfile, the docker-compose.yml file together with the images?

Answer (score 0):

The Dockerfile is the instructions used to create an image. Once that image is created, others can run the image without the Dockerfile.

The image itself should contain all of the components to run your application like the binaries, libraries, and any scripts (this is your source code if you have an interpreted language like JavaScript).

The docker-compose.yml is a configuration of how to run your image. This includes settings like where to publish ports, and how to mount volumes, which do not go inside the image itself.

---

Therefore, if you have copied your image, then all you need to run it is the docker-compose.yml.

---

Note that I do not recommend transferring images with save/load. You will find the same layers already shipped being transferred again. Instead, a registry server can be used, even in a disconnected environment by [running your own registry](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry). This keeps track of which layers are new and speeds up the transfer in addition to reducing disk space used by images.